# Gradle executable not found on Windows 7

Tags: gradle, failed-installation

This is the first time of using [Gradle][1], using version 2.1.

I unzipped the zip file to the directory `D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1`. I updated the environment variables ,and restarted my machine.But this is the result of testing:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>ECHO %GRADLE_HOME%
D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1

C:\Users\Administrator>ECHO %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin

C:\Users\Administrator>gradle -version
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Administrator>d:

D:\>cd D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1

D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1>gradle -version
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1>cd bin

D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1\bin>gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_11 (Oracle Corporation 25.11-b03)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 x86

D:\JavaTools\gradle-2.1\bin>
```

I'm really very confused. I just want to import the spring-framework source code from github to my Eclispe or IntelliJ.If you have other solutions ,pls tell me !
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Have you restarted your machine? What is the result of `echo %GRADLE_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: In your log, the second command which worked was `grable` not `gradle`.  You need to copy & paste the actual text from the console rather than manually type it, otherwise we could be wasting our time with your typos!

Comment: Any environment variable changes in a cmd.exe session are local to that session, and any system changes to the environment variables do not affect current processes - they must be restarted.  It seems likly that this is an operator error, but you have provided insuficient information to know that.  Verify the environment variables as @Tom has suggested, and add the results to the question as diagnostic evidence.

Comment: Ok,this error also exists,anyway, the spring-frame work is builded into the IntelliJ,so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue.The system variable %GRADLE_HOME% wasn't being created for some reason.

`echo %GRADLE_HOME%` returned `%GRADLE_HOME%` for example.

So I set the variable with setx, which comes with win 7 and above. Download [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546) to use it in XP.

- Run cmd.exe in administrator.
- Write `setx GRADLE_HOME <path to gradle> /m`

example `setx GRADLE_HOME C:\Programming\gradle\gradle-2.4 /m`

Reset cmd and test with `echo %GRADLE_HOME%`.
Then add `%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` to your path system variable.

Comment: For anyone trying to find "path to gradle" for Enide Gradle on Windows, it's deep inside `%USERPROFILE%/.gradle`.

Comment: in windows 10, we don't even need to install setx , it works after doing setx GRADLE_HOME [PATH] /m
but still not sure why the system variable %GRADLE_HOME% wasn't being created in the first place...

Comment: `<path to gradle>` is the place you extract your downloaded gradle file. IT IS NOT inside .gradle directory

Answer (score 0):

(In Win 7,)Dont bother with %GRADLE_HOME% etc .. 
Just copy your path including the bin folder:  C:\gradle-2.14-all\gradle-2.14\bin 
AND paste it in your system variable path after the semi column ;